# Flutter WebView Plugin stop listen in android

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I'm new in flutter. Im using flutter_webview_plugin. Im trying to initiate webview in my flutter app. in ios (simulator) worked perfectly ( showed up both print ) while in android ( emulator ) only showed up 1 print .

What I noticed here is, somehow emulator suddenly stop listen after retrieve the view .

[Left is android , right is ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8caeF.png)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterWebViewPlugin.close();
    _onUrlChanged = flutterWebViewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((url) {
      if (mounted) {
        print('outside if block');
        if (url.contains(
            '${EnviromentConfig.baseUrl}/?status_id=1')) {
        print('inside if block');
          Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
          _redirect(uri);
        } else if (url.contains(
            '${EnviromentConfig.baseUrl}/?status_id=0')) {
          Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
          String message = uri.queryParameters['message'].replaceAll('_', ' ');
          Navigator.pop(context);
          final snackBar =
              SnackBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red, content: Text(message));
          widget.parentScaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      }
    });
  }
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _onUrlChanged.cancel();
    flutterWebViewPlugin.dispose();
  }
```